# ARM printing hexadecimal number from register (not using C)

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm trying count vowels contained a String in an ARM program, and then print the number of vowels counted in hexadecimal to the console.  I can see in the register r2 that it is counting correctly (in this case 0x2), but something that I'm doing is preventing the number from transferring to r0 and printing correctly.   Can someone please point me in the right direction?  I can not use any C print commands, just SWI_WriteC to print to the console.  (Note: Everything I can find online uses C for printing numbers)

```
SWI_WriteC  EQU &0      ;output character in r0   
SWI_Exit    EQU &11     ;finish program

            ENTRY

Start       ADR r1, text        
            MOV r2, #0          ;counter for number of vowels
            BL ParseChar        ;call to parse each character and test if vowel
            BL PrintNumber      ;call PrintNumber subroutine, prints number of vowels   
            ALIGN           
            SWI     SWI_Exit    ;finish


ParseChar   LDRB    r0,[r1], #1 ;load a character in r0
            CMP r0, #0          ;testing if null 
            BNE TestChar        ;if not null, TestChar subroutine
            MOV     pc, r14     ;if null, return

TestChar    TEQ     r0, #'a'    ;test if character is an a
            TEQNE   r0, #'e'    ;if not above, test if it is an e
            TEQNE   r0, #'i'    ;if not above, test if it is an i           
            TEQNE   r0, #'o'    ;if not above, test if it is an o
            TEQNE   r0, #'u'    ;if not above, test if it is a  u
            TEQNE   r0, #'A'    ;if not above, test if it is an A
            TEQNE   r0, #'E'    ;if not above, test if it is an E
            TEQNE   r0, #'I'    ;if not above, test if it is an I
            TEQNE   r0, #'O'    ;if not above, test if it is an O
            TEQNE   r0, #'U'    ;if not above, test if it is an U
            ADDEQ   r2, r2, #1  ;if vowel was found add 1 to R1
            B       ParseChar   ;returns to ParseChar           

PrintNumber LDRB    r0, [r2], #1  ;load number from r2  
            SWI     SWI_WriteC    ;print 
            MOV     pc, r14       ;return


text        DCB     "a1u",&0a,&0d,0     

            END
```

Note:  This is my first post, so please forgive any formatting errors.  I'm also very new to ARM (this is my 1st program).

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that `SWI_WriteC` takes the ASCII code of a character to print and then prints it to the console.  So, if `r0` is 2 on entry, it will print the character with code 2.

However, the character with ASCII code 2 is not the digit 2.  It is a non-printing character.  The ASCII code for the digit 2 is 50, or 0x32.  In fact, the codes for digits 0 to 9 are 48 to 57, or 0x30 to 0x39, with the letters A to F at 65 to 70 (0x41 to 0x46) and lower-case letters a to f at 97 to 102 (0x61 to 0x66).

So, what you want is a routine that takes a number in the range 0 to 15, converts it into the ASCII code for the relevant digit or letter and then passes that ASCII code to `SWI_WriteC`.

That will work, assuming you don't have any more than 15 vowels.  If you have 16 or more, your hex number will have two or more digits, and this is where things get a little trickier.

Comment: This is close, but `LDRB    r0, [r2], #1` in `PrintNumber` is loading the byte value at the address which is the number of vowels!  That is definitely not right.  We need to change it to `mov r0, r2`, to transfer `r2` to `r0` which is probably where `SWI_WriteC` takes it's arguments.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was it.  I did what Luke suggested, as well as changed it to mov r0, r2 and it worked great!  Thanks again for the help!